# Совместить все строки в списке со строками другого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть массивы

```
m1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
m2 = ['String4', 'String5', 'String6']
```

как можно добиться этого?

```
['string1String4', 'string2String5', 'string3String6']
```

Comment: воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией `zip()` и оператором `+`

Answer (score 5):

```
res = list(map("".join, zip(m1, m2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы понимать, что представляет из себя `zip`, можно расписать его:

```
m1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
m2 = ['String4', 'String5', 'String6']
m3 = list()
for i in range(min(len(m1), len(m2))):
    m3.append(m1[i] + m2[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
m2 = ['String4', 'String5', 'String6']

x = [i1 + i2 for i1, i2 in zip(m1, m2)]
```